# Automatization reading in .csv files in Python with adaptive paths

Tags: python, pandas, csv, path

I am a rookie when it comes to python or coding in general. I set up a script, reading in various .csv files. I got a private notebook and a work notebook.

How can I automate the .csv reading for files with the names "1.txt", "2.txt" ... "22.txt" etc?
And how can I automatically adapt the path where the data is, depending on the system/notebook, as usernames change.

```
c1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\saram\Desktop\workspace\data\20200108Solid\1.txt", sep='\t', header=0, skiprows=range1+range2, usecols=range3)
c2 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\saram\Desktop\workspace\data\20200108Solid\2.txt", sep='\t', header=0, skiprows=range1+range2, usecols=range3)
c3 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\saram\Desktop\workspace\data\20200108Solid\3.txt", sep='\t', header=0, skiprows=range1+range2, usecols=range3)
c4 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\saram\Desktop\workspace\data\20200108Solid\4.txt", sep='\t', header=0, skiprows=range1+range2, usecols=range3)
c5 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\saram\Desktop\workspace\data\20200108Solid\5.txt", sep='\t', header=0, skiprows=range1+range2, usecols=range3)
c6 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\saram\Desktop\workspace\data\20200108Solid\6.txt", sep='\t', header=0, skiprows=range1+range2, usecols=range3)
c7 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\saram\Desktop\workspace\data\20200108Solid\7.txt", sep='\t', header=0, skiprows=range1+range2, usecols=range3)
c8 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\saram\Desktop\workspace\data\20200108Solid\8.txt", sep='\t', header=0, skiprows=range1+range2, usecols=range3)
```

Would be grateful, if you can help me with that <3

Sara

Comment: If the file names are the same across both systems, you can make the path to the files a variable and pass it to the script.

Comment: I would use glob to generate a list of files in the folder and then create a function to iterate over the list and read each file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting to put number in place of `{}`

```
name = "path/filename{}.txt".format(number)
```

and you can do it in loop  `for number in range(1, 9):`

You could also use list to keep files as `c[0]`, `c[1]` because you may use them in other loop

```
c = []

for i in range(1, 9):
    name = r"C:\Users\saram\Desktop\workspace\data\20200108Solid\{}.txt".format(i)
    df = pd.read_csv(name, sep='\t', header=0, skiprows=range1+range2, usecols=range3)
    c.append(df)
```

---

You can also use `os.listdir("folder")` to get filenames

```
import os

c = []

folder = r"C:\Users\saram\Desktop\workspace\data\20200108Solid"

for name in os.listdir(folder)
    if name.endswith('.txt')
        fullname = os.path.join(folder, name)               
        df = pd.read_csv(fullname, sep='\t', header=0, skiprows=range1+range2, usecols=range3)
        c.append(df)
```

or `glob.glob("folder/*.txt")`

```
import glob

c = []

for fullname in glob.glob(r"C:\Users\saram\Desktop\workspace\data\20200108Solid/*.txt")
    df = pd.read_csv(fullname, sep='\t', header=0, skiprows=range1+range2, usecols=range3)
    c.append(df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

This would give me all csv files in one dataframe/panda?
How about, if I want to read it into one variable?
What is actually better for statistical analysis later on: one huge panda, or a lot of independent pandas? :-P 
Sorry, if my usage of vocabulary does not fit the python rules of conduct.

Sara

Comment: it doesn't give you all in one dataframe but (like in your code) it creates many dataframes but it keeps them in one list - `c[0]`, `c[1]`, etc.. - instead of using separated variables `c1`, `c2`. You can use this list with `for`-loop - `for df in c: do_something(df)` - to make code shorter. As for statistical analysis: if you have to use all data in analyze then use one dataframe.

Comment: ah great, thank you a lot.
How would I define the range, if I want to skip one of the files/one number?

`for i in range(1, 9):`

Comment: you can use `remove()` to remove one item `a = list(range(1,9))` `a.remove(4)`  `a.remove(6)` `print(a)`. But for short range you can write it manually `[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8]`. Eventaully use other list `if x not in [4,6]:` - ie.  `for x in range(1, 9): if x not in [4,6]: print(x)`

Comment: you can also use `set()` like `a = list( set(range(1,9)) - set([4,6]) )` but set sometimes can change order and you may have to sorted it `a = sorted(a)` or `a.sort()`